Adding \kern to Thai language in babel breaks line breaking
If I add a \kern in Thai text, it seems to break line breaking. (Disclaimer: I don't read or write Thai.)
How can I fix this?
(I'm using \kern to add a little bit of unbreakable space, so happy with alternatives that have same effect.)
MWE
%! TeX Program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[import, main]{australian}
\babelprovide[import]{thai}
\babelfont[thai]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{Noto Sans Thai}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{thai}

\foreignlanguage{australian}{23}
แต่เราเทศนาเรื่องพระคริสต์ผู้ทรงถูกตรึงตายบนไม้กางเขนซึ่งเป็นหินสะดุดสำหรับพวกยิวและเป็นเรื่องโง่ๆสำหรับพวกต่างชาติ
\foreignlanguage{australian}{24}
แต่สำหรับผู้ที่พระเจ้าทรงเรียกทั้งพวกยิวและพวกกรีกพระคริสต์คือฤทธิ์อำนาจและพระปัญญาของพระเจ้า
\foreignlanguage{australian}{25}
เพราะความเขลาของพระเจ้าก็ยังฉลาดกว่าสติปัญญาของมนุษย์และความอ่อนแอของพระเจ้าก็ยังเข้มแข็งกว่ากำลังของมนุษย์

\bigskip

\foreignlanguage{australian}{23}\kern 2pt
แต่เราเทศนาเรื่องพระคริสต์ผู้ทรงถูกตรึงตายบนไม้กางเขนซึ่งเป็นหินสะดุดสำหรับพวกยิวและเป็นเรื่องโง่ๆสำหรับพวกต่างชาติ
\foreignlanguage{australian}{24}\kern 2pt
แต่สำหรับผู้ที่พระเจ้าทรงเรียกทั้งพวกยิวและพวกกรีกพระคริสต์คือฤทธิ์อำนาจและพระปัญญาของพระเจ้า
\foreignlanguage{australian}{25}\kern 2pt
เพราะความเขลาของพระเจ้าก็ยังฉลาดกว่าสติปัญญาของมนุษย์และความอ่อนแอของพระเจ้าก็ยังเข้มแข็งกว่ากำลังของมนุษย์
\end{document}

[Can't upload images at the moment for some reason.]

Put the \kern 2pt inside the \foreignlanguage{australian}{23 \kern 2pt} ...

This is not related to thai. You are disabling hyphenation. With luatex you can use \wordboundary (with other engines you can use something like \kern30pt\nobreak\hskip0pt)
See also Why does LaTeX neither break at nor hyphenate after a "user kern"?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\textwidth 30pt
\begin{document}
23 hyphenation

23\kern30pt hyphenation

\ifluatex
23\kern30pt\wordboundary hyphenation %lualatex
\else
23\kern30pt\nobreak\hskip0pt hyphenation
\fi
\end{document}



Ha thanks! Any advantage on use \wordboundary over just \hskip0pt everywhere for all engines? i.e., should I put the extra if logic in my code?

Will both preserve non-breaking nature of \kern?

well rechecking with \raggedright: you need the \nobreak that I removed before. But apart from this, yes.

Sigh. That makes all my test files fail (because of the extra \penalty). Oh well. At least it works.

With an mbox the breaking is restored.
Note that with the Babel option onchar=ids font you don't need to set the language.
David's own scripture package also seems to produce the correct output with a regular space.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scripture}
\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[import, main]{australian}
\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{thai}
\babelfont[thai]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{Noto Sans Thai}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\mbox{23\kern 2pt}%
แต่เราเทศนาเรื่องพระคริสต์ผู้ทรงถูกตรึงตายบนไม้กางเขนซึ่งเป็นหินสะดุดสำหรับพวกยิวและเป็นเรื่องโง่ๆสำหรับพวกต่างชาติ
\mbox{24\kern 2pt}%
แต่สำหรับผู้ที่พระเจ้าทรงเรียกทั้งพวกยิวและพวกกรีกพระคริสต์คือฤทธิ์อำนาจและพระปัญญาของพระเจ้า
\mbox{25\kern 2pt}%
เพราะความเขลาของพระเจ้าก็ยังฉลาดกว่าสติปัญญาของมนุษย์และความอ่อนแอของพระเจ้าก็ยังเข้มแข็งกว่ากำลังของมนุษย์

\begin{scripture}[1 Corinthians 1:23--25]
\vs{23} แต่เราเทศนาเรื่องพระคริสต์ผู้ทรงถูกตรึงตายบนไม้กางเขนซึ่งเป็นหินสะดุดสำหรับพวกยิวและเป็นเรื่องโง่ๆสำหรับพวกต่างชาติ
\vs{24} แต่สำหรับผู้ที่พระเจ้าทรงเรียกทั้งพวกยิวและพวกกรีกพระคริสต์คือฤทธิ์อำนาจและพระปัญญาของพระเจ้า
\vs{25} เพราะความเขลาของพระเจ้าก็ยังฉลาดกว่าสติปัญญาของมนุษย์และความอ่อนแอของพระเจ้าก็ยังเข้มแข็งกว่ากำลังของมนุษย์
\end{scripture}
\end{document}



Except you're not supposed to have a space after \vs :). There's a \kern put in (which can be controlled using the verse/sep option. This is to avoid line breaks between the verse and following text. This post was to try and solve the problem for the scrpiture package.
